# Find list item URL from the local file path C#

Tags: splistitem, links

I have a local folder that is linked with a document collection in SharePoint.  When I modify/add/remove files in this folder and its' sub-folders, it all syncs up with SharePoint. I need to determine the URL for an item/file using the local file path so that I can create an anonymous link programatically.  I can hack it together but I'd rather use the same mechanism this folder setup uses.

So, go from this:
`C:\Users\Me\My Corp\Something - Documents\Account Management\Bob\January 2020 Reports\Suzy\awesome.xlsx`

to this:
`https://ourSPsite.com/sites/Something/Shared Documents/Account Management/Bob/January 2020 Reports/Suzy/awesome.xlsx`

All my searches always come up with how to manipulate lists and items via SharePoint `ClientContext`, not how to look at a local file and figure out where it lives in SharePoint.

Here's my hack

```
 var startIdx= localFilePath.IndexOf("Bob");
 var listItemUrl = localFilePath.Substring(startIdx).Replace('\\', '/');
 var itemUrlFull = $"{siteFullUrl}/Shared Documents/Account Management/{listItemUrl}";

 var link = web.CreateAnonymousLinkForDocument(itemUrlFull, ExternalSharingDocumentOption.View);
```

There's a handy context menu when you right click a file/folder in Explorer that says `View Online`.  I'd like that chunk of code!